# Как установить classpath python для одного из интерпретаторов

Tags: python, terminal

На данный момент установлено несколько версий интерпретатора python
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тест кейсы запускаю отдельности командой, например

> python -m pytest -q --tb=short
>   02_User_Profile/test_09_change_password.py

Но так как на данной машине не работал, видимо по умолчанию используется интерпретатор, который не определяет модуль pytest.py и возвращает ошибку

> /usr/bin/python: No module named pytest

Заменил в запросе версию python на python3.5.
Возможно ли каким либо образом, не изменяя запрос на `python3.5 -m pytes...` изменить настройки, дабы вызывать тест-кейс старым способом?

Comment: Установить pytest для требуемой версии питона, не?

Comment: Я работаю в PyCharm, там для каждого сценария можно установить свою версию интерпретатора. По-моему, в вашем случае - самое оно.

Answer (score 1):

Видя такое разнообразие интерпретаторов на одной машине, я бы посоветовал Вам использовать [virtualenv](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) для создания независимых изолированных окружений.

Это также решило бы проблему необходимости указания конкретного интерпретатора. Достаточно лишь один раз создать виртуальное окружение с необходимой версией Python.
Например, если Вам необходимо работать с python3.5, то достаточно двух команд:

```
virtualenv --python=python3.5 venv
source venv/bin/activate
```

После этого у Вас в созданной директории venv будет персональная копия python со своим pip (при установке модулей с помощью pip они также будут установлены в виртуальное окружение).

Для выхода из этого окружения нужно достаточно ввести в терминале:

```
deactivate
```

Плюс ко всему, такой подход позволит быстро разворачивать необходимое окружение на любой новой машине, если предварительно сохранить список зависимостей в отдельный файл,

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

а в новом виртуальном окружении просто установить все эти модули:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```